# Conda Cython Build PYD/SO Files

Tags: python, cython, conda

I have built a module using "conda build packagename".

However, the built module ends up in "\Anaconda\conda-bld\work".

The module can only be imported (using "import packagename")if I cd into this directory, then run Python. I have tried placing the files in "\Anaconda\conda-bld\work" in "\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages", however I am not able to import the module from any directory; I must be in "\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages".

Is the only solution to put the .PYD file/ .SO file next to the executable Python file or is there a way to let Python know there is a new module installed?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the conda build script, you need to install the files, not just build them. For Python, this typically means running `python setup.py install` in the build.sh, and including `python` in your build dependencies so that the `python` will install into the build environment.